# look at row of dataframe and return result(x) if majority of items on row are also x

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

First copy/paste and run my code below then read the following:

I am trying to figure out a way to make a new column (i.e. `df['F']`) that returns a BHD if BHD occurs on the same row 3 or MORE of the 5 times and the same for SHD which also needs to return on the same column as BHD (all results should be on 1 column)

I have added column F for a template of the answer I require

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = ('S', 'SCL', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SL', 'S', 'S', 'BCL', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD','B','S')

df['B'] = ('SCL', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SL', 'S', 'S','BCL', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD','B')

df['C'] = ('BCL', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD','B','S','SCL', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SL', 'S')

df['D'] = ('BCL', 'B', 'SCL', 'SHD', 'SL', 'SCL', 'SHD', 'SL','S','SCL', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SL', 'S')

df['E'] = ('SL','BCL', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'BHD', 'B','SCL', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SHD', 'SL')

df['F'] = ('0','0','0', 'SHD','0','0','0','0', 'BHD','0','0', 'SHD', 'SHD', '0', '0')


print(df)
```

Comment: What if both SHD and BHD are 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that using something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['F'] = np.select([df.eq('BHD').sum(axis=1).ge(3),
                     df.eq('SHD').sum(axis=1).ge(3)],
                    ['BHD', 'SHD'], default='0')
```

`eq('BHD')` - This returns the dataframe containing booleans: `True` if the string is `BHD` and `False` otherwise.

`sum(axis=1)` - This sums the `True`s row-wise and gets the number of times the string occurs in a particular row

`ge(3)` - `ge` stands for 'greater than or equals to' - It returns `True` if the number of counts is greater or equals to 3

`np.select` - This replaces the cases where you get 'SHD' three or more times with 'SHD' and the same for 'BHD'. When both of them are `False`, it returns the default value of '0'.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. I inserted the line of code you provided however only received NaN when running/printing the code.  Also I also would like the SHD results on the same column as the results returning BHD

Comment: Is that because there are no rows where 'BHD' occurs exactly three times? For 'SHD', you can use the same code, just replace the string: `df['SHD'] = df.eq('SHD').apply(sum, axis=1).map({3: 'SHD'})`. Also, `eq` is looking at rows where the string occurs *exactly* three times. If you want "greater or equals to", you can use `ge` (>=) rather than of `eq` (==).

Comment: I would suggest to just use `.sum(axis=1)` instead of `apply`, since apply will be quite slow.

Comment: Thank you Erfan and Vlad for your replies.  Vlad you are correct I thought I created a dataframe where the occurrence of 3 BHD's on a single row occurred.  I have amended the code in the question so now 3 BHD's occur on row 8

Comment: Ok - brilliant. Does the code do what you want it to do now?

Comment: Not 100%. I have added edited the question and added column F of what I require.  I did say in the original that I require the entire result on 1 column. ie not a column for SHD results and a seperate column for BHD result. And yes as you suggested in your comment I require the code to include 3 or more results not the rows just equal to 3. Just see col F. This is what I am looking for it to look like

Comment: also require result to be 0 rather than Nan

Comment: Understood. I have updated the answer - hopefully, now it does what you need it to.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)